# beeline query in bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

simple working beeline query below;  when i put in script it will run but I want to put a hivevar for the path, how do I accomplish this as when i put in my script `.properties` file the ='path' does not seem to work.  I am missing something with these single quotes i think and I just can't seem to get it to work.

`maxValQuery.hql`

```
WORKING: INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/tmp/maxVal' select max(${hivevar:MAX_VAL_COL}) from ${hivevar:FACT_TABLE};
WANTED:  INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY ${hivevar:PATH_ON_HDFS} select max(${hivevar:MAX_VAL_COL}) from ${hivevar:FACT_TABLE};
```

`script.sh`

```
 #! /bin/bash
 # I want to add --hivevar PATH_ON_HDFS=${maxValPathOnHDFS} 
    beeline \
        -u $hiveServer2 \
        --hivevar DATABASE_NAME_ON_HIVE=${dbNameOnHive} \
        --hivevar FACT_TABLE=${mainFactTableOnHive} \
        --hivevar MAX_VAL_COL=${factTableIncrementalColumn} \
        -f ${maxValQueryFile}
```

`script.properties`

```
dbNameOnHive=poc
mainFactTableOnHive=factTable
factTableIncrementalColumn=aTimeColumn
maxValQueryFile=maxValQuery.hql
#maxValPathOnHDFS='/user/tmp/maxVal'
#I believe problem is above with the single quotes, yes I uncomment when i execute :P
```

Comment: what error do you get when you with script after un-commenting (`maxValPathOnHDFS`) lines in script and .props file?

Comment: @BigDataLearner  Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:27 mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'DIRECTORY' in destination specification (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: @BigDataLearner Fixed by removing the single quotes from the properties file and just doing '${hivevar:MAX_VAL_PATH}' I feel silly

Comment: did you try with out single quotes: `maxValPathOnHDFS=/user/tmp/maxVal`?

Comment: just removing single quote in prop file should also work

Comment: @BigDataLearner confirmed that the single quotes ARE required around the hive var as without it failed on same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed single quotes from properties file and added around hivevar in query:
`#maxValPathOnHDFS=/user/tmp/maxVal` & `'${hivevar:PATH_ON_HDFS}'`